# Do TCP Ports belong to the Host or the IP Address?

Tags: tcp

I understand TCP/IP addresses, and I understand ports, but I don't know whether the ports are tied to the Host (and hence one host gets one port 80), or whether the ports are tied to the IP Address (and hence one host with 2 NICs/IP-Addresses gets 2 port 80s)?

Comment: Your question is really not meaningful and so an answer to it is not likely to be meaningful. What would the distinction be between "one port 80" and "2 port 80s" exactly?

Comment: Well, with 2 port 80s, you could have two completely different web servers and web sites (...and yes I know how you would *actually* host multiple sites on one host...this was a theory question...and it is meaningful, and I got meaningful answers below)

Comment: What if those two completely different web servers and web sites both use the same port but distinguish what data to serve based on the difference in IP address? It's purely a semantic question whether you want to consider them different ports (because they can be distinguished by IP address) or the same port (because the port is the same). Are two Core i5-3570K CPUs "the same CPU" or not?

Answer (score 1):

A port belongs to an IP address. If a host has two NICs , and a program binds to only one IP address, the same port can still be used by another program(given that it binds to another IP address).

Comment: If it's "that same port" that can still be used by another program, that would mean there's just one port, though it can be used by two programs. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'both'.

If you bind to a specific IP:port, you can have as many bindings using the same port number as you have IP addresses.

If you bind to `0.0.0.0:port`, or `::port` in IPv6, the port is global to all possible IP addresses of the host, including those that don't exist yet.

But I agree with @DavidShwartz, the question is a bit ill-formed. The fact is that the endpoint is defined by `IP:port`, not just by `port`. A port isn't a real thing that you can actually count. It's just a 16-bit number.

Comment: It's just a 16-bit ... which is specified by a document, and therefore it is part of something, so it belongs to it, even if it doesn't exist. So not thaaaat ill formed as you claim. ;)

Comment: RFC 793 specifies the format of the field in the TCP header, and therefore its value range. The actual values aren't countable in any meaningful sense.